# How to start a paragraph under an inserted image

Tags: floats, positioning

I am new to latex and I am trying to make a text appears after the graph using this code but is is not working what should I add ?

```
\begin{figure}%[h]

  \centering

  \includegraphics[width = 16cm, height = 13cm]{rbf}

  \caption{a 1 pca }

  \label{fig:1PCA}

\end{figure}

\par\bigskip  
\noindent

remarque :I didnt inclide all the plots in this report because there  
are too many of them
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) BTW: [You should add at least loading of a document class and package `graphicx` and `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Schweinebacke I already did that on the top I just took this code portion

Comment: You might want to look at the float package (`texdoc float`), in particular, the `H` position specifier. Alternatively, you may want to not have your image inside a figure environment at all.

Comment: do not do `\includegraphics[width = 16cm, height = 13cm]` just specify one of width or height, otherwise latex will distort the figure stretching by different amounts in each direction.

Comment: you do not ever need \par in a document (it is the same as a blank line) and similarly you do not need \noindent as latex would not indent if you did not start the paragraph, but note that a figure is a floating enviornment that will typically not appear at the position it appears in the source, that is why they have \caption so you can refer to then indirectly, even if placed at top of a later page.

Comment: The figure option [h] means "here if possible" so it will work most of the time, but you should also have a plan B.  You can put text inside a figure.  It is basically just a savebox.